# How do I refresh my activity after deleting data from database (using DAO)

Tags: java, android, dao

How should I "refresh" my `Activity` after tap on button which will delete all records in data base? For now, after tapping on icon which is responsible for deleting data, I have to re-run my app to see changes - such as empty `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Why don't you use LiveData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already indicated, you need to use LiveData or rxJava 2 to update activity every time you change data.

LiveData : https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-with-livedata-android-jetpack-cbf89b677b47

RXJava 2: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by add `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` onClick your button

I hope it will work with you .